# How to configure NGRX/Data for AOT compilation

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data, ngrx-data

I have a standard setup from the NGRX data docs with one Entity. Everything works with JIT but when I do AOT then I get following Error:

```
...
Function expressions are not supported in decorators in 'entityConfig'
'entityConfig' references 'ɵ0'
...
Consider changing the function expression into an exported function.
```

My entity config:

```js
const entityMetadata: EntityMetadataMap = {
  Identifiers: {}
};

export const entityConfig = {
  entityMetadata
};
```

My module:

```js
...
import { entityConfig } from './store/entity-metadata';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, EntityDataModule.forRoot(entityConfig)]
})
...
```

The error is thrown here:
`EntityDataModule.forRoot(entityConfig)`

Versions:

```js
"@angular/core": "^8.1.1",
"@ngrx/data": "^8.6.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^8.6.0",
```

Comment: Would Angular Ivy compilation help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be solved by using the `EntityDefinitionService` like this:

```js
import { EntityDefinitionService } from '@ngrx/data';
import { entityMetadata } from './store/entity-metadata';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule]
})
export class NotLazyLoadedFeatureModule {
  constructor(private eds: EntityDefinitionService) {
    eds.registerMetadataMap(entityMetadata);
  }
}
```

But the `EntityDefinitionService` expects the `EntityMetadataMap` directly, without wrapping it in an Object.

```js
export const entityMetadata: EntityMetadataMap = {  -> Use this
  Identifiers: {}
};

/* export const entityConfig = {  -> Not needed anymore
  entityMetadata
};*/
```

Worth mentioning is that I have the Store split up to multiple modules. They are technically not lazy-loaded but my `app-store.module.ts` looks like this:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    EntityDataModule.forRoot({}), <- Only needed once
    NotLazyLoadedFeatureModule, <- Import not lazy loaded modules here
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument()
  ]
})
export class AppStoreModule {}
```

Comprehensive explanation about the difference between JIT and AOT:
https://gist.github.com/chuckjaz/65dcc2fd5f4f5463e492ed0cb93bca60

Answer (score 1):

that's a known issue if you use a reducer as an arrow function.
please read this part: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers#creating-the-reducer-function

> Note: The exported reducer function is necessary as function calls are not supported by the AOT compiler.

you have to wrap every reducer with a proper javascript function.

Comment: I'm using NGRX-Data and one benefit is that it creates the Reducers (among other stuff) for me, so atm there are no Reducers in my code and I would like to avoid implementing them just for AOT compilation.